# How do I enable a "Bicycle AND Boy" search in Solr?

Tags: solr, expansion

I have solr up and running but I cannot get the results when I search "Bicycle AND Boy", works fine for "Bicycle Boy".  What are the steps to enable such searches?

Comment: Are you using dismax? What does your schema look like?

Comment: Make sure you use uppercase 'AND' - lowercase wont do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the configuration for Solr is set to use OR as the default query operator. Look for this line in the schema.xml file:

`<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>`

You can also reference the Solr Tutorial for more details on querying... http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Querying+Data

Answer (score 1):

Can you try searching Bicycle AND Boy without quotations?

Comment: naa, i guess I need to expand my queries a little. Somehow the config file must use some settings.